# switch spring boot bean definitions by property and allow custom bean

Tags: java, spring-boot

Assume an `interface Service {}`. My platform provides two implementations of this interface:

- `FooService`
- `BarService`

What I want now is that the user can choose via yaml which service to use. In addition, if he'd rather use a `CustomService`he should be able to ignore both default implementations and provide his own bean.

Note: This is a starter project, so the user adds a dependency to my jar and should get either FooService, BarService or CustomService injected, depending on his yaml/configiguration.

Here's what I tried:

- In `@ConfigurationProperties` I have a field `String serviceType = "foo"` (foo is the default)

In my AutoConfiguration, I provide both beans:

```
 @EnableConfigurationProperties(MyProperties.class)
 public class MyAutoConfiguration  {
   @Bean
   @ConditionalOnMissingBean(Service.class) // only active if no custom present
   @ConditionalOnProperty(name="service-type", havingValue = "foo")
   public Service fooService() {
      return new FooService();
   }

   @Bean
   @ConditionalOnMissingBean(Service) // only active if no custom present
   @ConditionalOnProperty(name="service-type", havingValue = "bar")
   public Service barService() {
      return new BarService();
   }
}
```

Creating a first simple test, I assumed to get FooService injected, but instead I got an ApplicationContext Exception because no bean is registered for the `Service` interface. In this test, I do *not* set any value for "service-type" in the yaml, I rely on the default "foo".

Where is my mistake? Can't I have ConditionalOnMissingBean on two beans? Is the default "foo" not considered when evaluating the  condition on property? Are there other ways to solve the general problem: Provide more than on default bean and still allow users to overwrite?

Comment: First you are checking on 2 different types of missing beans (the types are different). Also the `ConditionalOnProperty` check the `Environment` for properties so if you set a default in a `@ConfigurationProperties` annotated bean that isn't taken into account. Instead set the `match-if-missing` for the default to `true`

Comment: The different types where a c&p mistake. The second info is valuable ... this hopefully will solve my issue. Care to add it aas an answer so I can give credit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `@ConditionalOnProperty` is implemented by the [`OnPropertyCondition`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/OnPropertyCondition.java) which looks in the `Environment` to check if a property exists. Adding property on in a `@ConfigurationProperties` annotated class isn't going to add that value to the properties. Hence the check still fails.

However the `@ConditionalOnProperty` als has a [`matchIfMissing`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/ConditionalOnProperty.html#matchIfMissing--) attribute which you can set. The default value is `false` so if you set it to `true` for the value of `foo` it will match if the value hasn't been explicitly set.

```
@ConditionalOnProperty(name="service-type", 
                       havingValue = "foo", 
                       matchIfMissing=true)
```